# Exporting Base64 image in html table to excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, base64, export-to-excel

I am trying to export base64 image with html table but image never gets exported and it shows a cross sign instead of image in the excel file. I am having the following code :

```
 <html>
<head>
  <script language="javascript">
    var tableToExcel = (function () {
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
                return function (table, name) {
                    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
                    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
                }
            })()
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Export image -->
  <input type="button" id="export-data" src="images/icon/icon-excel.png" value="Export to Excel" onclick="tableToExcel('tableResult', 'W3C Example Table')" />

  <table id="tableResult" border="1" class="pvtTable" data-numrows="6" data-numcols="10">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="1"></th>
      <th class="pvtAxisLabel">Product Name</th>
      <th class="pvtColLabel" colspan="1" rowspan="2">610164</th>
      <th class="pvtColLabel" colspan="1" rowspan="2">110152909</th>
      <th class="pvtColLabel" colspan="1" rowspan="2">B1</th>
      <th class="pvtColLabel" colspan="1" rowspan="2">Derived</th>
      <th class="pvtTotalLabel" rowspan="2">Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th class="pvtAxisLabel">Thumbnail12Prod</th>
      <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th class="pvtRowLabel" rowspan="1" colspan="2"><a href="#"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></a> </th>
      <td class="pvtVal row0 col4" data-value="1">1</td>
      <td class="pvtVal row0 col7" data-value="  "></td>
      <td class="pvtVal row0 col8" data-value="  "></td>
      <td class="pvtVal row0 col9" data-value="  "></td>
      <td class="pvtTotal rowTotal" data-value="1" data-for="row0">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th class="pvtRowLabel" rowspan="1" colspan="2"><a href="#"><img src="data:image/png;base64, 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" alt="Red dot" /></a> </th>
      <td class="pvtVal row1 col4" data-value="  "></td>
      <td class="pvtVal row1 col5" data-value="1">1</td>
      <td class="pvtVal row1 col8" data-value="  "></td>
      <td class="pvtVal row1 col9" data-value="2">2</td>
      <td class="pvtTotal rowTotal" data-value="3" data-for="row1">3</td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>

</body>
</html>
```

As soon as I click on the Export to Excel button, excel file gets generated but image is not embedded in it and instead of image it shows a cross sign.
Please suggest

Comment: @zevee : Thanks for the information and I will keep a note of it in future. As of now, Can you please provide a solution for my issue as you can easily copy and paste the snippet in your notepad and give me suggestions for the same

Comment: Any suggestions from any one. Still I havn't got any proper answer for this question. Thanks In Advance

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm trying to export an image into an excel document as well but I always end up with w cross sign. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Jesse James : Sorry James. No success yet and its still the same

Comment: Any news on this subject?